# CiviDiscount: How do I disable the automatic member discount for additional participants?

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

I was disheartened to learn that the automatic discount I created to give members a discount off the conference registration fee applies to other participants the member registers even though they are not members. I think the same goes for if the member isn't registering themselves but someone else--if they are logged in as a member, the discount applies for whoever they are registering, even though they are not members. Does anyone know how to be more restrictive with the discount code so it only applies to the member, and not their plus ones? We are using CiviDiscount 3.3.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think CiviDiscount does what you want.  If you are on Drupal you could use a webform.

Comment: (and use Conditionals to determine what prices are offered to whom based on their membership status?).

Answer (score 1):

You could use some CSS to display/hide certain rows of your Price Set for only the first participant. This is only partially an answer to your question, in that it will allow a member to only purchase one registration at the discounted price, but that one registration won't be restricted to that member (they could purchase one registration for another individual).

1. Create a Price Set with a checkbox price field (let's call it "Tickets") with two options: First Registration, Additional Registrations.
2. Create your Discount code, applied only to the "First Registration" option.
3. Use that Price Set for your Event and visit the registration page to determine the exact CSS classes of those price field options. Will be something like "Tickets-row1" (or whatever your checkbox price field is).
4. Then add the following styles to the Price Set Pre Help (adjusted to your specific classes):

`<style>
.crm-event-additionalparticipant-form-block .Tickets-row1 {display: none;}
.crm-event-register-form-block .Tickets-row2 {display: none;}
</style>`